Mottled polygon fill using QGIS
I want to give my polygons a mottle fill, by that I mean a more randomised shapeburts type of appearance.
For example, the blue-green layer in the below image has a random darker green colour within it as well.

I have experimented with shapeburst but it looks too uniform. I can see there is a random point fill and I wonder if there is a way to use that but I'm not sure.

I suggest you supplement your current shape burst fill with a random marker fill(you need to scroll down a bit, I can't link to the exact location), which you in turn randomize using rand() on data defined override for the symbol size and maybe even the marker type.

How do you use rand() for the marke type? It only allows integers.

Add a randomized integer attribute using e.g. rand(1,4), then using CASE you may define a marker type to use for each number. It's not that obvious, sorry.

Got it, thanks for your answer.

To get decimal random values, create integer random values and divide by a power of 10, e.g.rand (1,100)/100


Create random points inside polygons.

Create Voronoi polygons.

Style them with Shapreburst and for one of the colors use a data driven override that modifies the color of the symbol, e.g. using an expression like
darker (@symbol_color , rand (75, 110))




Thank you for your detailed answer, but I just wanted to explain why I didn't pick it. With Erik's answer I was able to achieve what I wanted within the original layer rather than having to generate new ones. The symbology of the voronoi polygons also were too angular.
